# Trying to implement combobox in Access 2010 form

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

Suppose I have 3 tables in Microsoft access like so:

patron (**patronId**, contact, street name, city, post code, email, *companyid*)

company_type(**companyid**, name, notes)

patron_phone(***patronId*, phone_number**) multi-varied attribute

I'm trying to create a form where it is possible for a user to view all the above information. Essentially the form looks like this:

DONATING PATRON

Contact:

Street Name:

City:

Postcode:

Email:

Name from company_type: (combo box that lists 'individual', 'company' or 'charity' as a text)

SUBFORM

Telephone Number:

I'm trying to create a combo box that allows the user to select individual, company or charity when adding a new record - this corresponds directly to the companyid number - but it isn't showing any entries.  Essentially what I'm trying to do is allow the user to select the company_type.name as opposed to companyid.  I have used the form query wizard but and defined my relationships properly.

Apologies for not showing any pictures but I don't have a high enough reputation score

Comment: Essentially what I'm wanting is to display the companyid foreign key in patron as the name attribute in company_type.  How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your column count to 2, your column widths to "0; 2" and your bound column to 1.  This will allow you to display your Company Name in the drop-down, but the value of the combo will be CompanyID (which is what you want to store in your table).